# how to represent a bridge in eagle pcb schematics?

Tags: pcb, schematics, eaglecad

[image: pcb]

i'm trying to show that points 7,8,10,11 are connected to ground and point 9 is connected to R18 resistor. but the visuals is misleading. how to create that "jump"

[image: pcb]

(sorry i don't know the correct lingo for that operation, please edit if you know, thankyou)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eagle wants you to put junction points where two lines connect each other. Otherwise gives a warning in ERC (Electrical Rule Check). I suggest you this notation;

[image: Eagle Ex.]

This way Eagle becomes sure, if it's a connection or just a different net passing over. To put junction points you can use 'Junction' from toolbar. But if you draw your nets with 'Net' tool rather than 'Wire' tool junctions will be automatically put.

[image: Eagle Tbx.]

Comment: "'Net' tool rather than 'Wire' tool" got it!